# In Vue, can you create a props by another props concatenated with a string, without using a computer property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Are there an alternative to computer property, when it comes to making a props from a props that's concatenated with a string, like so?

```
<MyComponent
    :someProps="anotherProps+aString"
/>
```

I'm wondering if you can build this with a javascript expression. I've tried many different combinations of syntax. Or there is some other way.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a computed property?

Comment: I have a simple props that contains a translated text and want to suffix it with a sign, and would prefer not to have alot of computed properties if it can just be a simple one-liner.

Comment: You could call a method to mix them dynamically in all occurences in that case. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just concatenation, you probably use interpolation between the 2.
Let's say `anotherProps` and `aString` are 2 props, you could write

```html
<MyComponent
    :someProps="`${anotherProps}${aString}`"
/>
```

Any vanilla JS expression can be written inside of the double quotes, even ES6 so yeah, it should work.